# Null Pointer Exception when trying to compare one field to update records

Tags: apex, map

I have a requirement where I need to compare Child object records of one parent and update values based on that.
Parent Record -> Contact

Child Record 1 -> Driver (has lookup to contact)

Child Record 2 -> Vehicle (has lookup to contact)

I have to update matched__c field on `Driver__c` object, if `Vehicle State__c` matches with `Driver State__c`

When I am trying to get map value it is throwing

> **Null pointer error Attempt to de-reference a null object.**

**Using below logic to perform update:**

```
Set<Id> ConIds = new Set<ID>();
for(Driver__c d : [Select Id, Contact__c,Status__c, Matched__c from Driver__c where Status__c ='Active']){
   ConIds.add(d.Contact__c);
}

Map<Id, Vehicle__c> mapStateVehicle = new Map<ID,Vehicle__c>([Select ID, Vstate__c, Contact__c from Vehicle__c where Contact__c IN: ConIds]);

for(Driver__c d : [select Id, Name, dState__c, Contact__c from Driver__c where Name like 'XYZ%']){
    if(d.dState__c == 'IL' && mapStateVehicle.get(d.Contact__c).Vstate__c  == 'IL' ) // mapStateVehicle.get(d.Contact__c).Vstate__c receiving null pointer expcetion
    {
        Matched__c = true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: There is a possibility that you have a driver record without a Contact__c field populated. In the if condition before accessinga VState__c , add a check if the map contains contact field populated: `mapStateVehicle.containsKey(d.Contact__c)`

Comment: @Raul mapStateVehicle.containsKey(d.Contact__c) is returning false .How to get Contact ID from MAP?

Comment: `mapStateVehicle.containsKey(d.Contact__c)` false means your key is not found in a map, thus means `mapStateVehicle.get(d.Contact__c)` is null and the error is because you are performing a dot operation against a null value.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to our forum.

I think that your query is probably giving you more than one result. 
Try something like this:

```
Set<ID> ConIds = new Set<ID>();

for(List<Driver__c> d : [SELECT Id, Contact__c,Status__c, Matched__c FROM Driver__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active]) {
          for(Driver__c driver : d) {
            if (driver.Contact__c != null) {
                ConIds.add(driver.Contact__c);
        }

      }
  }

// Rest of your code.. you maybe need to make changes there as well.
```

This should populate the Set if any Driver__c is found on you query.

Comment: thanks for your response, ConIds are getting values, the problem is mapStateVehicle.get(d.Contact__c).Vstate__c . I am not sure how to get Contact Id and State from Vehicle__c.